# Added Stopwords but doesn't seem to work

Tags: r, tm, stop-words

I have added a few words to my stopword list but when I process it and look at word frequency, one of the words seems to be stuck.

```
myStopwords <- c(stopwords('english'), "glove", "kgi")
corp <- tm_map(corp, removeWords, myStopwords)
```

I then create a TDM and run a word frequency and 'glove' pops up.  There are other variations such as 'glovechina' & 'glovesgrain' that I'd expect to be there but not 'glove' itself.  Am I missing something?

Example of lines from CSV source:

- KGI 999 SZ11 GLOVE LEATHER PROT LOW
- KGI 10054BC10 GLOVE SZ 10.5
- SAL ILPG10A1010H GLOVES LTHR

Code:

```
corp <- Corpus(DataframeSource(x))
corp <- tm_map(corp, tolower)
corp <- tm_map(corp, PlainTextDocument)
corp <- tm_map(corp, removePunctuation)
corp <- tm_map(corp, removeNumbers)
myStopwords <- c(stopwords('english'), "glove", "kgi")
corp <- tm_map(corp, removeWords, myStopwords)
corp <- tm_map(corp, stemDocument)
corp <- tm_map(corp, stripWhitespace)

tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(corp)

# print terms
dimnames(tdm)$Terms
save(tdm, file="tdm.RData")
# frequent terms
which(apply(tdm, 1, sum) > 20)
findFreqTerms(tdm, lowfreq=20)
```

Comment: That's weird. Are you sure that the 'glove' that appears in the word frequency table is exactly 'glove', without white spaces or other invisible characters? Did you `stripWhitespace` before computing the tdm?

Comment: I've just tested it and it works for me, could you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: I just added a few example rows and the code.  I'm using the stripWhitespace.  kgi is removed but glove isn't.  Not sure why.

Comment: OK, the explanation is that *glove* is removed in the `removeWords` step, but `stemDocument` creates a new occurrence of it by removing the final *s* of *gloves*. Maybe you should switch these two steps.

Comment: Bingo.  Thank you very much.  Evidently I need to dust off my programming hat.